# How to recapture more efficiently?

Tags: blitz

I know this sounds ridiculous but I want to learn the hand movement for recapturing in chess. It seems like a good fast way to recapture especially in blitz. Here is an example if you don't know what I'm talking about (the way they quickly recapture/capture a piece).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9NG8J2yow4

Answer (score 2):

Practice makes perfect. I've seen several different ways on how to capture pieces. It's not really something that you learn, but more like something that goes automatically. So, just try it a few times at home (without thinking, so it goes automatically), and do what feels the most *natural*.

Answer (score 2):

Since the most common capture is a pawn taking a pawn, this is the one to practice most.  (There is a video of a piece maker who designed the pieces so that the capture would seem natural.)
My method is to pick up my piece with my thumb and index, then I force the captured piece into the other fingers.

Comment: You cant say "there is a video.." and not link to the video! :) Do you remember anything else about the pieces?

Comment: I do not even remember what colour they were.  A friend linked me to the video, but I did not find the video remotely interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Replay the video and copy it? The only way is practice.